# ¿Como puedo solucionar Undefined variable y problemas derivados de ello en PHP?

Tags: php

Estaba intentando crear una pagina web en PHP para probar mis conocimientos y iba bien hasta que me aparecieron los errores la verdad no se a que se deban y no puedo ser muy descriptivo debido a que soy amateur lo que se es que mi tres primeros errores comienzan con mi archivo controller.php estos son los errores:

> Notice: Undefined variable: respuesta in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejc1\controllers\controller.php on line 11

> Warning: include(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejc1\controllers\controller.php on line 11

> Warning: include(): Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejc1\controllers\controller.php on line 11

aqui dejo el código del controller.php :

```php
<?php
class MvcController{

    public function plantilla(){
        include "views/templete.php";
    }

    public function enlacesPaginasContrller(){
     
            $enlacesController= $_GET["action"];
            include $respuesta;
            $respuesta=EnlacesPaginas::enlacesPaginasModel($enlacesController);
        

    }
}
?>
```

como ven no soy un experto y es un código simple pero me atasque en esa parte, y mi ultimo problema es con mi archivo model.php también note que solo afecta una parte del la barra de navegación específicamente al inicio.

aquí el error:

Notice: Undefined variable: module in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejc1\models\model.php on line 16

no estoy seguro a que se deba ni como si como solucionarlo agradeciera la ayuda aquí va el código de la navegación:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php?action=inicio">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?action=nosotros">Nosotros</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?action=servicios">Servicios</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?action=contactenos">Contactenos</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

y este es el código del modelo

```php
<?php

class EnlacesPaginas{

public static function enlacesPaginasModel($enlacesModel){

if($enlacesModel == "incio" ||
   $enlacesModel == "nosotros" ||
   $enlacesModel == "servicios" ||
   $enlacesModel == "contactenos" ){

    $module ="views/modules/" .$enlacesModel. ".php";
   }


return $module;
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Los tres errores tienen el mismo origen: usar la variable $respuesta sin haber sido definida y que por tanto no tiene valor. Luego, el error en el modelo es que si $enlacesModel no es ninguno de los esperados, entonces $module se queda sin definir, deberías tener un valor por defecto ¿qué tal 'inicio'? La verdad es que eres menos que amateur, te recomiendo que mejores tus conocimientos antes de seguir avanzando con tu página web, al menos deberías ser capaz de entender ese tipo de errores, ver la causa, y solucionarla por ti mismo, No obstante, tu pregunta está bien expuesta, eso es bueno ;)

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando la variable $respuesta sin haber sido definida, de ahí el Undefined variable. A consecuencia, la instrucción include recibe un parámetro que está vacío, de ahí Filename cannot be empty. Estás intentando incluir un archivo '' que no existe y de ahí Failed opening '' for inclusion.

Tu error es que intentas usar $respuesta antes de haberla definido. Tienes que hacer el include después de haberle dado valor a $respuesta:

```
$enlacesController= $_GET["action"];
$respuesta = EnlacesPaginas::enlacesPaginasModel($enlacesController);
include $respuesta;
```

En este punto, la verdad es que la variable $respuesta ni la necesitas. Tampoco $enlacesController. Además, deberías comprobar si recibes o no 'action'. Podría quedar así:

```
include EnlacesPaginas::enlacesPaginasModel(
    isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : ''
);
```

El otro error que tienes es que, en el modelo, si $enlacesModel no es ninguno de los esperados, $module se queda sin definir, y de ahí Undefined variable. Lo adecuado es que tengas un valor por defecto, el más indicado es 'inicio'.

Tu clase puede quedar así:

```
class EnlacesPaginas
{
    public static function enlacesPaginasModel($enlacesModel) {
        switch ($enlacesModel) {
            case 'nosotros':
            case 'servicios':
            case 'contactenos':
                $module = 'views/modules/' .$enlacesModel. '.php';
                break;
            default:
                $module = 'views/modules/inicio.php';
                break;
        }

        return $module;
    }
}
```

Como te decía en mi comentario, la verdad es que eres menos que amateur. Te recomiendo que mejores tus conocimientos, o casi mejor dicho, habilidades. Errores como esos deberías ser capaz de depurarlos por ti mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Tu clase es muy correcta, para que te devuelva lo que necesitas debes hacer estos cambios:

```
class EnlacesPaginas{
    public function enlacesPaginasModel($enlacesModel){ 
        if( $enlacesModel == "nosotros"||
            $enlacesModel == "servicios"||
            $enlacesModel == "contactenos") {
                $module = "views/modules/".$enlacesModel.".php";
                return $module;
            }
        $module = "views/modules/inicio.php";
        return $module;
    }
}
```

En la solución que te propongo primero se verifica el `if` y si se cumple retorna `$module`, si no se cumple sale del `if` y devuelve `$module` con el valor de inicio.